# Page Title in drupal

Tags: 7

In my drupal site some places the page titles are not shown.that are the term or a block but not a page.how can i show that title

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Your question is a bit vague and needs some clarification and as you've seen has been marked as a duplicate. For example a block in Drupal terms is within a page, it's not its own page. You may want to check out the [Page Title Module](http://drupal.org/project/page_title). Also, you have not really demonstrated that you've tried anything, see: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

You can show a custom title on each page with the function drupal_set_html_head("your title").
You call that function in a custom module with a preprocess hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can add or alter a page title with [drupal_set_title('My custom page title !')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7)